# CSS animation creates flickering "bounding box" when animating padding

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a circular div to give a ripple-like effect, filling it's container. There should be an initial ripple (the border), followed by the main shape expanding to fill the container.

I'm accomplishing the ripple by animating the border-width of the circle div in combination with the padding, thereby pushing the border outwards.

The problem is, the bounding box of the circle div flickers white while the padding is animating. If I remove the padding portion of the animation, and just animate the border-width, there is no flickering, so I know it is the padding that is causing the problem.

```
@keyframes circle {
0% {
    width:0.001px;
    border-width:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
50% {
    width:0.001px;
    border-width:100px;
    padding:400px;
}
100% {
    width:125%;
    border-width:100px;
    padding:400px;
}
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8f0qby8/3/) to demonstrate. Click the grey box to activate it.

EDIT: Upon testing in Firefox, it works as expected. Possibly webkit-specific?

EDIT 2: 2 common solutions I've seen for fixing generic "flickering during animation" bugs are to add the styles

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

or

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to the offending element. I've tried these, and neither have fixed it.

Originally, I accomplished this animation using multiple circular divs and a series of classes with transitions (representing various states of animation), then triggering those classes using setInterval delays. Now that I'm more familiar with CSS animation, I'm trying to recode it to be more CPU-friendly, as the old method chugged along on older laptops. I'm assuming a single circle div compared to multiple, and a single animation being called rather than constant adding and removing of classes would be more efficient?

Comment: Nothing happens for me when I click on the gray box.  I am using firefox.

Comment: @RohitGupta He is using webkit properties. It will work only in Chrome and Safari maybe.

Comment: @RohitGupta as Manoj mentioned, I was using webkit properties, but have updated the fiddle to work on Firefox as well. I noticed from testing in Firefox that there were no issues, so this could be a webkit-specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### The bugs cause

The webkit bug has something to do with the padding being animated (as you noted). In this example, I have replaced the paddings role with the width and height.

#### Other changes

- The animation is added on click with a class and then the class is removed. This way the animation can be reused over and over.
- I have changed the keyframes so that at the end of the animation, the white slowly turns transparent.

#### A note on prefixes

- The `animation` property [is very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), the only prefix you may need is `-webkit-`
- The native `transition` property [is more or less 100% supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) without prefixes
- The native `transform` property is [very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform), the only prefix you may need is `-webkit-`

#### Example 1

Tweak to your liking, border is on the same element as the background, so they move at the same time.

```js
$("#circleCont").click(function() {
  $(".circle").addClass('animated');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".circle").removeClass('animated');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0 solid #FFF;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  background-clip: content-box;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
#circleCont {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s;
}
#circleCont:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
#hero {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.animated {
  animation: circle 4s forwards
}
@keyframes circle {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    border-width: 0px;
    height: 0;
  }
  25% {
    border-width: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    border-width: 100px;
    padding: 400px;
    background: #FFF;
  }
  100% {
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    border-width: 100px;
    padding: 400px;
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero">
  <div id="circleCont">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Example 2

In this example, the border is set on a different element. The background element is given an `animation-delay` so that it starts slightly after the border animation.

```js
$("#circleCont").click(function() {
  $('.circle').addClass('animated');
  $('.border').addClass('animated');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.circle').removeClass('animated');
    $('.border').removeClass('animated');
  }, 4500);
});
```

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  border: solid 100px transparent;
}
#circleCont {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s;
}
#circleCont:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
#hero {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle.animated {
  animation: circle 4s forwards;
  animation-delay: .5s;
}
.border.animated {
  animation: circle 4s forwards;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
@keyframes circle {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: #FFF;
  }
  50% {
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    background: #FFF;
    border-color: #FFF;
  }
  100% {
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    border-color: #FFF;
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero">
  <div id="circleCont">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="border"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see... this seems to work, but for the life of me, I can't understand why? What is pushing the border away from the main body of the circle, if not the padding in your example? I can't seem to break down how this is working, especially since I had already made use of the width and height in my code, but your use of it seems to somehow fix the bug. Would you mind explaining how you came to this solution?

Comment: As well, I would like to delay the growing of the main circle, so that it does not start at the same time as the ripple. I've attempted to do that here, but the flickering returns if the 2 don't grow at the same time. https://jsfiddle.net/x8f0qby8/7/

Comment: About why it works: [See this example](https://jsbin.com/lofami/edit?html,css,output). The first div has no height or width, only padding (100px padding on the top, right, bottom and left sides). The second div has a height and width of 200px which takes up the same space. The look identical when they are empty.

Comment: Check out my edit. Example 2 has a separate element for the border ripple. That way we can delay the main circles animation start. It has to be a separate element to work.